# Exact word based search in Solarnet & Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, search, cpu-word

We have an application where solar-net is integrated with mongodb for searching and full text search is working fine. Now we have to change full text search to exact word based search for example if "DELL" is entered in Search input field, it should only bring up results that are "DELL", and not "DELL Inspiron". Please let us know how to change full  text search to exact word based search.Is there any regular expression to do this. Search is based on multiple fields. Please help me.

Thanks
Tarlok

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex as following :

To Search all names starts with "DELL"

`db.collectionName.find( { "name" : { $regex : "^DELL.*", $options : "i"} } )`

To Search all names contains "DELL" :

`db.collectionName.find( { "name" : { $regex : "DELL.*", $options : "i"} } )`

here `$options : "i"` defines ignore case

for more detail visit [This](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

Comment: We are using solarnet. If we use this then we overkill the features of solarnet. Moreever this is not exact word based search. Please let me know if you have any other solution.